# Why CATextLayer render half width comma "," to full width comma "，"

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

below is the code

```
import UIKit
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
let txtLayer = CATextLayer()
txtLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 150, height: 50)
txtLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
txtLayer.string = ",，"
txtLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale

view.layer.addSublayer(txtLayer)
let b = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 90, width: 40, height: 20))
b.text = ",，"
b.textColor = UIColor.red
view.addSubview(b)
```

[image: comma render image]

I want to CATextLayer render "," like UILabel to display correct symble “,” ,not "，" .
How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CATextLayer` and `UILabel` use different fonts by default. You can see this by printing their `font` properties:

```
print(txtLayer.font!)
print(b.font!)
```

This prints these for me:

```
<UICTFont: 0x7fe3718061d0> font-family: "Helvetica"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 36.00pt
<UICTFont: 0x7fe371909400> font-family: ".SFUI-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt
```

If you set them both to the same font, and to the same size so that it's even more obvious, you'll see that the text they display look exactly the same.

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
let txtLayer = CATextLayer()
txtLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 150, height: 100)
txtLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
txtLayer.string = ",，"
txtLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
txtLayer.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 50) as CTFont
txtLayer.fontSize = 50

view.layer.addSublayer(txtLayer)
let b = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 140, width: 150, height: 100))
b.text = ",，"
b.textColor = UIColor.red
b.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 50)
view.addSubview(b)
```

[image]